# CSS Grid - right justify specific columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I am looking for a way to right-justify specific columns (not all columns) in a grid in CSS without having to explicitly specify a special class or style for each column entry.  For example:

```
<style>
    .myclass {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    }
</style>

<div class="myclass">
    <span>AAAA</span>
    <span>BBBB</span>
    <span>CCCC</span>
    <span>DDDD</span>

    <span>EEEE</span>
    <span>FFFF</span>
    <span>GGGG</span>
    <span>HHHH</span>
</div>
```

So, I want the first and third columns right justified, and the second and fourth columns left justified without having to explicitly specify style or class for each span.

Thanks!

Comment: did you consider nth-child selector?

Comment: Assuming the columns follow the DOM order of course....☺

Comment: The problem with nth-child selector is that I want it auto-repeated to affect all elements in that column not specified one (nth-children).

Comment: nth-child can auto repeat to target a group of specific elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nth-child` selector can do the trick

```css
.myclass {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

span:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  <span>AAAA</span>
  <span>BBBB</span>
  <span>CCCC</span>
  <span>DDDD</span>

  <span>EEEE</span>
  <span>FFFF</span>
  <span>GGGG</span>
  <span>HHHH</span>
</div>
```